# how to create multiple initial commits in the master branch?

Tags: git

I came across a rather strange Git repository and wondered how to create it. (Of course this probably doesn't make practical sense, just curious)

---

In the master branch, create multiple starting commits (none of them have a parent).

The repository address is `git://github.com/ossxp-com/gitdemo-commit-tree.git` and the diagram is as follows ↓

[image: gitdemo-commit-tree.git]

**How should this be implemented?**

This may be a simple request, but I've been thinking about it for a really long time and haven't figured out exactly how to do it, so I'm here for help.

---

1. commit directly, which takes the current commit as parent
2. checking the documentation for commit and checkout, I don't see the option I want, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: What reason do you have to try to merge that many unrelated commits together? Couldn't you create an empty initial commit, branch commits E, G, H, I, and J off from the initial commit and have a much cleaner merge history?

Comment: @sphennings This is not a question of practical use. I just saw this Git repository and was curious about the way to construct it. It's like a maths practice problem. Just now I already knew, at least one way of constructing it and wrote it into the answer.

Comment: Good to know. It might be a good idea to [edit] the question to make it clearer that you're interested in pushing the boundaries of git functionality and not looking for information on git best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

### orphan branch merging

This is the result of orphan branch merging, which can be reproduced by the following operations.

```
git init
'text' > "A.txt"
git add -A;git commit -a -m 'A'
git checkout --orphan 'new_branch'
'text' > "B.txt"
git add -A;git commit -a -m 'B'
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --allow-unrelated-histories 'new_branch'
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

```
*   3805411 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'new_branch'
|\
| * b2af1fd (new_branch) B
* 70e2a07 A
```

### subtree add

First, use reset to restore to the state before merging.

```
git reset 70e2a07 --hard
```

Then, the commit in the orphan branch is spliced into the current tree through the subtree.

```
git subtree add -P 'B_repo' 'new_branch^{}'
```

In this way, similar effects can be obtained. Of course, the two methods are completely different in other aspects.

```
PS>git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   50f7c25 (HEAD -> master) Add 'B_repo/' from commit '47b72dbdebd593bde75a80df7ff28544b2982ff1'
|\
| * 47b72db (new_branch) B
* fd9bb52 A
```

Comment: This is correct. Note that Git is a little inconsistent in its labeling: `git switch` and `git checkout` use `--orphan` and call this an *orphan branch* while other parts of Git call this an *unborn branch*. Either way, you end up on a branch that doesn't exist until you make its first commit; at that point, you have a new root commit, i.e., a commit with no parent, and now the branch name exists. Merging will give you the multi-root setup. Git versions 2.9 and later will require the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option here but earlier ones just assume it.

Comment: This orphan / unborn state is necessary in a new, empty repository, because a branch name has to store the hash ID of an existing commit, and in that new repository, there aren't any commits yet. So whatever branch you are on, that branch doesn't actually exist yet. The `--orphan` flag just gives you a way to recreate this initial state in a repository that *does* have commits.